# Using npm to import ScrollMagic plugins for react project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, plugins, gsap, scrollmagic

I could install ScrollMagic with `npm install scrollmagic` for my React project.
Now I need a way to install the following plugin to make ScrollMagic work with GSAP

> plugins/animation.gsap.js

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue and I was able to get it working by following this [response](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues/324#issuecomment-105040652) on the ScrollMagic issues board.

```
var $ = require("jquery");
var ScrollMagic = require("scrollmagic");
require('scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap');
var gsap = require("gsap");
```

I added the code block to the top of the file where I was creating my various scenes.